# PL/SQL Trigger Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Problem:
There are three roles. 1) Student 2) Teaching Assistant(TA) 3) Teacher. Student and TA could be same person but with different role. Both Student and Teacher have a unique id called unity id. Their are various courses in courses table which students can enroll in and TA's can assist in. Their are various topics associated with each course which can be present in multiple course. Topics are present in different table.
Rules:
1) A TA cannot assist in the course in which he/she is a student.
2) Notification has be sent to both teachers who are taking the courses.

Requirement: Whenever a TA is enrolled(populated in "TA" table), we have to send notification to teacher if topics of same user as a TA and a student(Cid in Course_roster table which corresponds to topics in TOPICS table) overlaps.

So, I have created a Notification table which gets populated when the trigger is fired. Also I have created a trigger which I have messed up because I am doing PL/SQL for the first time.

I am attaching sample data from TA table, Course_roster table, Topics Table, and layout of Notification Table

```html
Course_Roster Table

CID             unityid
CSC440FALL14 tregan
CSC440FALL14 mfiser
CSC440FALL14 jander
CSC440FALL14 mjones
CSC540FALL14 aneela
CSC540FALL14 mjones
CSC540FALL14 jmick
CSC540FALL14 tregan


TA Table

CID             unityid
CSC440FALL14 aneela
CSC440FALL14 jmick
CSC540FALL14 jharla
CSC541FALL14 jmoyer

Topics Table

CID             TID     Topic Name
  
CSC440FALL14 100   Introduction to database design
CSC440FALL14 101  SQL:Queries, Constraints,Triggers
CSC540FALL14 500   Introduction to database design
CSC540FALL14 501     Storing data: Disks and Files
CSC540FALL14 502     Primary File Organizations
CSC540FALL14 503  Tree Structures
CSC541FALL14 502  Primary File Organizations
CSC541FALL14 503  Tree Structures


Notification table

t_unityid text s_unityid timestamp
```

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_TA
AFTER
INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON TA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE tid1 dbms_sql.number_table;
    DECLARE tid2 dbms_sql.number_table;
    DECLARE tid3 dbms_sql.number_table;
    DECLARE @unityid varchar2;
    DECLARE @unityid2 varchar2;
            
            Select @unityid= unityid from inserted
            Select @unityid2=unityid from COURSES Where COURSES.CID=inserted.CID
            
            Select tid1=t.TID from TOPICS t,COURSE_ROSTER c where t.CID=c.CID and c.UNITYID=UNITYID
            Select tid2=t.TID from TOPICS t,inserted where t.CID=inserted.CID

            tid3 := tid2 multiset intersect tid1;
        IF tid3.Count > 0
            insert into notification (unityid, notice, ta_unityid)
            values(@unityid2, 'Subject topic of TA is matching with course topics taken.',@unityid)
        ELSE
            PRINT 'TA ok to register'
END
```

There are many error in the code as I had no idea where the code was going. I really appreciate help go get me through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The trigger code snippet doesn't look like PLSQL code and hence you are having errors when compiled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please guide me which part to edit to make it work. I know there might be lot of changes required, but as I said, I am just a beginner, So I kind of messed up the code.

Comment: I do not know you requirements, best is edit your question and provide your table structure with sample records and be specific about what you are looking for. Thus others will be able to help you.

Comment: Your code won't compile because you are use T-SQL syntax rather that PL/SQL.  If you compare it to the sample code in the PL/SQL manual [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS653) you should be able to spot and fix your errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot @APC for pointing the error. I have updated the problem  in a more descriptive way. I will look around what you have suggested.

Comment: I have updated the problem in a descriptive way @Polppan.

Comment: @shubham90 Why `CID` and `unityid` columns are repeating in `Course_Roster` and `TA` tables? Why can't be those information in one single table?